# Clickonce - Roll back to previous verison

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, deployment, clickonce

As we know that clickonce stores the previous version information locally. When I go to 'add or remove program' to uninstall the application it shows popup to restore the application to previous state. after selecting it, the application is restored to the previous version installed.

Now I want the same functionality in my application by adding a button, On click of that button the application should restored to the previous installed version.

I searching this for long but I haven't found any solution so I am posting this question.